# Why use Student's t distribution rather than Student's z distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

So suppose I'm trying to decide whether to reject the null hypothesis that the mean of some random variable $X$ is zero based on the sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ computed from $n$ IID draws of this random variable.  Then normally I would do a $t$ test $$t=\frac{\hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}\;/ \sqrt{n}}$$

and check to see what the probability is that one would draw a more extreme value than $t$ from the $t$ distribution.

But why even bother scaling by $\sqrt{n}$?  Why not just use [Student's z-distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentsz-Distribution.html)?  After all isn't that the true distribution for the sample mean $\hat{\mu}=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$?  The only reason I can see to bother is so that for large $n$ Student's t distribution approximates the standard normal distribution, which might simplify computation, is this the only reason it's done?

Comment: good question. you might want to check out "on the transition from student's z to student's t" eisenhart 1979

Comment: (1) What's the variance of $X_i$? (2) "*Why not just use the student's z-distribution? After all isn't that the true distribution for the sample mean*?" -- what is this belief based on?

Comment: As a small matter of form, Student was the pseudonym used by W.S. Gosset and so should be capitalised like any surname or family name. (Edited accordingly.)

Answer (score 5):

Generally, when you do a statistical test, you want the null distribution of the statistic to have a stable form, so as to allow easy computation of P-values.

This is partly a historical consideration. In principle, there's no reason you couldn't use the unscaled statistic $\hat{\mu}/\hat{\sigma}$, as opposed to $\hat{\mu}/(\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}})$, and compare to the percentage points of a distribution that became successively narrower with sample size. But this would be very cumbersome if you didn't have modern computers to calculate those percentage points for you. Even today, when we do have computers that could do this calculation, having a relatively stable null distribution makes it easier to compare results from different studies involving different sample sizes. A t-statistic of 2.5 is easier to comprehend because it means roughly the same thing whether you have a sample of 100 or 100,000. You can't say the same about the unscaled z-statistic.

Comment: Nice answer. You have not mentionned that using either $t$ or $z$ is strictly equivalent because it is obvious. I would add it because (oddly) it is not clear for everyone, as shown by the upvotes to the first answer.

Comment: This holds when $\mu$=0.  Otherwise to get a central t you need to subtract $\mu$.

Comment: You don't get the t distribution with n-1 df if you don't divide by the square root of n.

Comment: In the test the value of $\mu$ used is the value under the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** *Added material to respond to some issues that arose in the comments.*

As stated by the reference the OP pointed to, $\hat \mu$ does not follow Student's z-distribution - $(\hat \mu -\mu)/s$ does. But *when* these distributional results hold in finite samples? *Only when the $X$'s are normally distributed*.

So you have to wonder: Under non-normality the usual t-statistic still converges to a standard normal by the Central Limit Theorem, because under the null it is a sum of random variables centered, and scaled by their standard deviation. Technically, it is the term $\sqrt n$ that prevents it for converging to zero.

So where does the statistic you propose, $(\hat \mu -\mu)/s$, converges to? Isn't it zero? *Irrespective of the true value of $\mu$?*
So what good is it for a statistic in non-normal samples if it gradually "loses" its finite sample distribution and tends to the same constant?

**ADDENDUM**
One can search and verify that if $Z_n$ follows a Student's- $z$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, and $T_{n-1}$ follows a Student's- $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, then the following relation holds between them:

$$T_{n-1} =Z_{n} \sqrt {n-1} \Rightarrow Z_{n}=\frac 1{\sqrt {n-1}}T_{n-1}$$

Assume that we have a size-$n$ sample of i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}$ following $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, both parameters unknown.  Setting

$$\bar X_n = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\;\;\; s^2 = \frac 1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X_n)^2$$

then we know that the random variable

$$\sqrt n\frac  {\bar X_n -\mu}{s} \sim_{\text{finite-sample}} T_{n-1}$$

and also that

$$T_{n-1} \sim_{\text{asympt}} N(0,1)$$

The important thing to note here is that $T_{n-1}$, has a) a finite sample distribution and b) an asymptotic distribution. This means that $T_{n-1}$ remains a non-trivial random variable *even asymptotically*.

Let's now turn to the $Z_n$ random variable. By previous results we have

$$Z_n = \frac 1{\sqrt {n-1}} \left({\sqrt n}\cdot\frac  {\bar X_n -\mu}{s}\right)  \sim_{\text{finite-sample}}\frac 1{\sqrt {n-1}}T_{n-1}$$

and this quantity follows a Student's-$z$ distribution. What is its asymptotic distribution? It is obvious that $Z_n$ converges to zero, since

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac 1{\sqrt {n-1}} = 0,\;\; T_{n-1} \xrightarrow{d}N(0,1)\;\; \Rightarrow Z_n \rightarrow 0$$

What does that tell us? That while $Z_n$ has a finite-sample distribution, *asymptotically it collapses to the  constant $0$*, i.e. it does *not* remain a non-trivial random variable asymptotically.

So, to respond to a comment, these two statistics  are *not* asymptotically equivalent -the one remains a random variable with a distribution, the other collapses to a constant. Therefore the tests based on $T_{n-1}$ are asymptotically valid while the tests based on $Z_n$ are not.

*Should we care?*  After all, our samples are always of finite size, why should we care what happens asymptotically?

Well, from the above it is obvious that while the distribution of $T_{n-1}$ "stabilizes" as the sample size increases (due to the existence of an asymptotic distribution), the distribution of $Z_n$ *does not*, as it gradually collapses to a constant. And we do not know *how* does this affects the shape of the collapsing distribution, and the related probabilities.

This means that, in order for our finite-sample test using $Z_n$ to be valid, for each $n$ we have to calculate the probabilities-critical values that interests us... Amusingly, the OP asked

> "why even bother scaling by $\sqrt n$?"

Because, the answer is,

> "if you don't bother scaling by $\sqrt n$,then you will have to very
>   much bother computing the CDF of $Z_n$ for the specific $n$"

Which approach is more time-efficient?

Now, when we move from normal to **non-normal samples**, the centered and scaled sample mean does not follow Student's-$t$ in the first place, and we are left only with the asymptotically valid normality result which now comes from the Central Limit Theorem (and not through Student's -$t$). In this case, using $Z_n$ even for small samples sizes introduces an unknown approximation error, and renders the statistical test results questionable.

**PS:** Historically, W.S.Gosset derived first Student's -$z$ distribution (since he was interested in *very* small sample sizes), and laboriously calculated critical values for $n\leq 10$. It was through his collaboration with R.A. Fisher that they turned from it to the Student's -$t$.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote? Could the person who downvoted provide some suggestions for improvement at least? Or point to possible mistakes in this answer?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you for asking the question I would also ask. Since I cannot find any mistake in the answer, perhaps the downvoter considered as negative that I have not provided mathematical formulas and proofs, but only verbal conversation... Apparently (s)he has no interest in communicating the reasons for the downvote, so I guess we will never know.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I didn't downvote, but I believe the t-test often provides a better small-sample approximation even if the normality assumption fails. Using t-quantiles gets one closer to the nominal coverage rate than using z-quantiles, and is obviously more conservative (and so safer than the z). It seems reasonable to expect the t-statistic to have heavy (say, polynominal rather than Gaussian) tails when we are forced to estimate $\sigma$, *regardless* of the sampling distribution of $X$, so the t-test seems more appropriate (but this is just heuristic).

Comment: @guy Thanks for contributing here. My answer has to do with whether it is _valid_ to use the Student-z statistic ("z" here of course has nothing to do with the standard normal) proposed by the OP, compared to the Student-t,  and not with what statistic performs _better_. Since the statistic related to Student's-z distribution does not converge to a distribution but to zero, using it cannot be valid, since we really have no distribution values against which to compare the obtained value of the statistic.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos apparently I didn't read the OP carefully enough; apologies.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I don't understand your answer. Under the null we drop $\mu$ and the two statistics are the same up to a multiplicative factor. So I don't see any difference if we use a test based on the $z$-statistic. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent In order for the test to be executed, after we calculate the value of the statistic, we need to compare this value with a value taken from a distribution. In the case of the usual t-statistic, theory tells us that we can use the Student's t-distribution with appropriate degrees of freedom, or the Standard Normal, because the t-statistic follows these, even if only asymptotically, in which case our test is valid only asymptotically -but at least it _is_ asymptotically valid. The statistic will "move" from following Student's- to following Standard Normal. CONTD

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  if we use the Student-z statistic, then of course we can calculate a value for it.  But then, can we use the values of Student-z distribution for comparison? _No_ because as $n$ increases this statistic loses its distribution and becomes a constant. And we cannot know up to what value of $n$ does it still behave like a Student-z random variable, so as to be valid to compare values.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos The tests are *equivalent* : one rejects the test based on $t$ if and only if one rejects the test based on $z$. Hence if one is asymptotically valid, the other one is too.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Sorry I was not the one who downvoted but this time I do, because you're claiming there are some differences between two equivalent tests.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos one has the normal approximation $t_n \approx {\cal N}(0,1)$ equivalent to the normal approximation $z_n \approx {\cal N}(0,1/\sqrt{n-1})$. Try to illustrate using simulations what you are claiming. **You can't, because the tests are the same**.

Comment: In other words, write down a R function returning 0/1 if the test based on $t$ returns $H_0$/$H_1$, and write down a R function returning 0/1 if the test based on $z$ returns $H_0$/$H_1$. **These two functions always return the same output**.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent a) regarding the asymptotic equivalence of the tests: the distribution $N(0,1/\sqrt{n-1})$ -to where this distribution converges as $n\rightarrow \infty$? b) Regarding the finite-sample tests for non-normal samples: here the usual statistic is not distributed according to Student's-t in the first place, and so how can we claim that the transformed statistic follows Student's z?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos The test is defined by a rejection rule. The asymptotic behavior of the test is *not* determined by the limit of the test statistic only. Here I think the point you miss is that, using the notations of my answer, the critical value $z^*= t^*\;/ \sqrt{n-1}$ goes to $0$ too, whereas the critical value $t^*$ goes to a non-null value.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Indeed it does. And it is compared to what critical value from what distribution that reflects what tail probability?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos The question of the OP is essentially the same as : "why to use $t$ as a statistic instead of $Kt$ for a constant $K$?". Using either $t$ or $Kt$ we get exactly the same $p$-values, the test are the same. The question is in fact "why to use the quantiles of $t$ and not the quantiles of $Kt$". We precisely choose the critical value (quantile) in order that the rejection rules are the same. The fact that $K$ depends on $n$ does not change anything.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Indeed. But this is not what we are discussing in this comment-conversation. I don't see you commenting on the "asymptotic validity" of the two approaches -something you have asserted a few comments back. You explicitly wrote "if the one is asymptotically valid, the other one is too".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Once you have understand the $p$-values are the same, how could you think that something differs between  a user using the same $p$-value as another user ? **The test based on $z$ is asymptotically valid because it is the same as the based on $t$**.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand, you ask why one uses
$$
t=\frac{\hat{\mu}}{\hat{\sigma}\;/ \sqrt{n}}
$$ 
and not 
$$
z= t\;/ \sqrt{n-1}.
$$
Using the test based on $t$, one rejects the null hypothesis when $|t|>t^*$ where $t^*$ is a quantile chosen in order that the test achieves the nominal level.

Using the test based on $z$, one would similarly reject the null hypothesis when $|z|>z^*$ where the quantile $z^*$ is simply given by $z^*= t^*\;/ \sqrt{n-1}$.

Thus, using either $t$ or $z$ provides exactly the same test: the conclusion drawn from the test based on $t$ is the same as the one drawn from the test based on $z$. **A hypothesis test is nothing but a rejection rule, the rejection rules are the same, hence the tests are exactly the same**. This is obvious, but I emphasize this point because the upvoted answer to the OP claims there are some differences !

One advantage of using $t$ is that the values of $t^*$ are more convenient than those of $z^*$. The approximation $t \sim {\cal N}(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$ is well-known, and it is well known how $t$ "looks like" ${\cal N}(0,1)$ for $n$ growing from $1$ to $\infty$ and in particular we know that $t^*$ decreases as $n$ decreases. For high values of $n$ the values of $t^*$ are close to the quantile of ${\cal N}(0,1)$, and it is not hard to learn by heart the (rounded) values of $t^*$ for small values of $n$.

In other words, the table of the $z$-distribution, giving the $z^*$, would be less digestible than the table of $t$-distribution.

Comment: Can the downvoter explains its downvote ?